# Android video plays but VideoView does not appear

Tags: android, maps, android-videoview

I'm attempting to play a video on top of a Google map when the user changes location.  Initially in the activity_main.xml the videoview is set to invisible. When the video is about to play I set the videoview be visible and setZOrderOnTop(true).

When the video is triggered by onLocationChanged the videoview does not appear.  But I can hear the audio from the video so I know its playing.

However if I play a video first in the onCreate, that plays successfully, appearing on screen.  And the onLocationChanged video also plays and appear on screen.

Why does the videovideo view not appear if I don't play a video in the onCreate?

**activtity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/top_message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="110sp" android:textColor="#66CCFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20sp" android:text="Default Text" />

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_message"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" /> 

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myVideo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap googleMap;
private TextView distanceTextView;
private VideoView videoView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    // setup overlay for text
    distanceTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.top_message);
    distanceTextView.setText("Text set onCreate");

    // setup overlay for video
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

    // setup google map data
    googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))).getMap();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // set current location and move map to that location
    if (location != null) {
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPosition, 15));
    }

    // if below is uncommented then secondvideo will also appear 
    //playVideo(new String("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.firstvideo));

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    distanceTextView.setText("Location has changed");
    playVideo(new String("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.secondvideo));          
}

private void playVideo(String videoFile) {
    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);

    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoPath(videoFile);
    videoView.start();
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            videoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            videoView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setZOrderOnTop()` cannot be used to change the z level dynamically.  From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop%28boolean%29),

> Note that this must be set before the surface view's containing window
>   is attached to the window manager.

Once the view has been attached, calls to `setZOrderOnTop()` do not have any effect.  One solution is to always have the `VideoView` on top and control whether it it is seen with `.setVisibility()` like you are already doing.  You can use one call `setZOrderOnTop()` in `onCreate()`, which is probably why it worked when you played a video in `onCreate`.

Comment: Thank you so much no other solution worked for me. Impressive! :)